# Github feature like Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: github, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Is there any service / feature of github.com just like Bitbucket Pipeline ? 
I'm actually want to push my master branch to FTP server (cpanel, apache) . It's really easy with Bitbucket Pipeline, but any way to do that in Github ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github now has a feature called [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), which allows you to execute arbitrary commands and processes triggered by events such as repository writes, pull request merges, and others similar to Bitbucket Pipelines. So your build/test/deploy stages can be run using Github's infrastructure, or you can move your app code to a remote location such as an FTP server, to kick off a code pipeline or update remote artifacts.

Comment: Do  you know if it also runs in Docker the same way that BitBucket pipelines do?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 I can't say it's *exactly* the same as BitBucket pipelines, but yes it's based around running your commands inside a container or VM which runs on top of Github's Runners (which can also be self-hosted). See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners

Answer (score 2):

GitHub itself doesn't provide this feature, but you can use GitHub apps, such as [Travis CI](https://github.com/marketplace/travis-ci).

> Travis CI enables your team to test and **ship your apps** with confidence. It’s built for everyone and for projects and teams of all sizes, supporting over 20 different languages out of the box, including Javascript and Node.js, Ruby, PHP, Python, Mac/iOS, as well as Docker, while giving you full control over the build environment to customize it to your own needs.

There is also other apps for continuous integration: https://github.com/marketplace/category/continuous-integration

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. You could however setup an internal build server using jenkins, circle ci, or travis ci. I have used both jenkins and circle ci both integrate well with github(It's fairly straight forward process). Jenkins is open source, where as circle ci is cloud base solution(it has a free tier). Both I believe could help solve your issue.